# Multiplying two matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to program a simple function that just prints out the product of two matrices,
the following is what i came up with. But its not working, and I just can`t figure out why.
It produces the wrong result. This is the output I get:

5.000000 12.000000 13.000000 
21.000000 40.000000 41.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
I was hoping someone could maybe tell me what the issue with this code is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
int rows;
int cols;
double *data;
 } matrix;

void mult(matrix a, matrix b){
    int m = a.rows;
    int n = b.cols;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        { 
          double c = 0;            
          for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++)
            {
                c += *(a.data +i*a.rows +k) * *(b.data+k*b.rows + j);
            }
            printf("%lf ", c);
              
        }
        puts("");
        
    }

}

int main(){
matrix a;
a.rows = 4;
a.cols = 2;
double data[] = {1,2, 
                 3,4,
                 5,6,
                 7,8
                 };
a.data = data;
matrix b;
b.rows = 2;
b.cols = 3;
double data2[] = {3,2,1,
                  5,6,7
                  };
b.data = data2;
mult(a,b);
}
```

Comment: time to use a debugger and do a step by step check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have on issue on how to get element, perhaps using a double data[][] can be easier

```
void mult(matrix a, matrix b){
    int m = a.rows;
    int n = b.cols;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            double c = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++)
            {
                c += a.data[i * a.cols + k] *
                     b.data[k * b.cols + j];
            }
            printf("%lf ", c);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel really stupid now, for some reason I mixed up rows and columns.